# Arch how to show program in list of open with

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, music-player

I just installed gnome-music. Now I try to open an mp3 file with this program but when I right click open with on my mp3 file, gnome-music is not showing.

How can it appear there so I can select it and set as default program to open audio files ?

Comment: Try opening the `.desktop` file for gnome-music (probably under `/usr/share/applications`) and see if it has `audio/mp3` under `MimeType=` and maybe report back?

Comment: There was no MimeType so I addedi it but the problem persists.